# Extracting values from JSON API using Python

Tags: python, json, request

I use an api to obtain information on a particular share.

```
{
  "Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-05-22",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
  },
  "Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2020-05-22": {
      "1. open": "183.1900",
      "2. high": "184.4600",
      "3. low": "182.5400",
      "4. close": "183.5100",
      "5. volume": "20826898"
    },
    "2020-05-21": {
      "1. open": "185.4000",
      "2. high": "186.6700",
      "3. low": "183.2900",
      "4. close": "183.4300",
      "5. volume": "29032741"
    }, and more...
```

I would now like to extract only the date, open,high to convert it into a CSV.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query"

querystring = {"outputsize":"compact","datatype":"JSON","function":"TIME_SERIES_DAILY","symbol":"MSFT"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "API KEY"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

info = response.json()

with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(info, fp)

f = open('data.json',)

data = json.load(f)

meta = data["Meta Data"]

for i in data['Meta Data']:
    print(i)

# Closing file
f.close()
```

output:

```
1. Information
2. Symbol
3. Last Refreshed
4. Output Size
5. Time Zone
```

I thought the information was in "Meta Data" but apparently not.
Can someone explain to me exactly what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your dict contains several dicts.

```
meta = data["Meta Data"]

# Contains dict

 "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
 "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
 "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-05-22",
 "4. Output Size": "Compact",
 "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"

timeSeries = data['Time Series (Daily)']['2020-05-22']

# Contains dict


  "1. open": "183.1900",
  "2. high": "184.4600",
  "3. low": "182.5400",
  "4. close": "183.5100",
  "5. volume": "20826898"
```

You can simply access values like this :

```
eventOpen = data['Time Series (Daily)']['2020-05-22']['1. open']
```

Try to play around with these objects and print their type and content so you can understand what they contain and how to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

But if I loop through "Time Series (Daily)", I only get the dates

Comment: Oh yeap, my bad, got mixed up with your brackets I'm updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The outcome of Time Series (Daily) was a big mess. 
A conversion into a proper CSV format was not possible.

Using pandas I formatted the data and was able to transfer the data into a proper CSV format.

```
meta = json.load(f)
data = meta['Meta Data']
data = meta['Time Series (Daily)']

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','open','high','low','close','volume'])
for d,p in data.items():
    date=datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
    data_row=[date,float(p['1. open']),float(p['2. high']),float(p['3. low']),float(p['4. close']),int(p['5. volume'])]
    df.loc[-1,:]=data_row
    df.index=df.index+1
df =df.sort_values('date')
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

```
          date     open     high      low    close    volume
0   2019-12-27  3776.82  3794.93  3775.26  3782.27  24437900
1   2019-12-30  3780.44  3780.44  3748.47  3748.47  18684000
2   2020-01-03  3787.57  3787.57  3745.54  3773.37  30343400
3   2020-01-06  3764.34  3764.34  3710.94  3752.52  28339400
4   2020-01-07  3760.09  3784.42  3748.13  3759.25  29853300
.... to continue ()...
```